Implement MapWithContent for place list and preview Route
Google recently up the beta version of the Car App that deprecate old templates and wrap all in a new one named MapWithContent.
do exist some examples to implement that?

https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation#migrate-to-mwct has some example code mapping the old templates to corresponding usage of the MapWithContentTemplate.

Hi Ben, thank you.  the process to load the map from the Google SKD, is still continue the same? Create a surfaceManager and configurate there the map, do u have an example of that?
I really appreciate your help
